# Watch still showing birthdays

Tags: calendar, apple-watch, watchos

I have a Series 2 with watchOS 3.1.

As shown in the screenshot below, I have birthdays turned off for the calendar app. However, they are still showing in the scroll view.

[image]

How do I rid my watch of birthday events?

Comment: The birthdays that appear in scroll view, do they have the little red birthday present beside them signifying that that is in fact where they are populating from? Not say, a previous sync with Facebook or a user-created reoccurring calendar event?

Comment: @NYKg yep. I wouldn't be asking otherwise.